Determinant calculation and Lagrange interpolation polynomial
I've been trying to solve the following IMO-related question.
Let $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ be $n$ different reals, prove that $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\prod\limits_{\substack{j=1\\ j\neq i}}^n\frac{1-x_ix_j}{x_i-x_j}=\begin{cases} 0,& \text{When}\;n\;\text{is even}\\ 1,& \text{When}\;n\;\text{is odd}\end{cases}$$
At the first glance I was thinking of the Lagrange interpolation polynomial $\displaystyle{\ell_i(x)=\prod\limits_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq i}}^n\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}}$ and one famous identity $\displaystyle{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n}\ell_i(x)\equiv 1$ because it looks so similar to the IMO-related question. As far as I know, there're two ways of proving this identity.
The first way is by observation. $\forall 1\leq i\leq n$, there is $\ell_i(x_i)=1$ and $\forall j\neq i$, there is $\ell_i(x_j)=0$. Now consider the following function $\displaystyle{g(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\ell_i(x)-1}$. We can then find that $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are $n$ different roots of $g(x)$. However, the degree of $g(x)$ is at most $n-1$, which leads to only one possibility that $g(x)$ is a constant function with $0$ degree. Therefore $g(x)\equiv 0$, which proves the identity $\displaystyle{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n}\ell_i(x)\equiv 1$.
Another way is using the Vandermonde determinant. Let $a_i=x-x_i$ for $1\leq i\leq n$. Then $$\begin{aligned}\ell_i(x)&=\prod\limits_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq i}}^n\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}=\prod\limits_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq i}}^n\frac{a_j}{a_j-a_i}=\bigg(\prod\limits_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq i}}^n\frac{a_j}{a_j-a_i}\bigg)·\frac{\prod\limits_{\substack{1\leq j<k\leq n\\j,k\neq i}}\bigg(a_k-a_j\bigg)}{\prod\limits_{\substack{1\leq j<k\leq n\\j,k\neq i}}\bigg(a_k-a_j\bigg)}\\
&=(-1)^{i-1}\frac{\bigg(\prod\limits_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq i}}^na_j\bigg)\prod\limits_{\substack{1\leq j<k\leq n\\j,k\neq i}}\bigg(a_k-a_j\bigg)}{\prod\limits_{1\leq j<k\leq n}\bigg(a_k-a_j\bigg)}\end{aligned}$$ Note that the denominator is just the Vandermonde determinant $$\prod\limits_{1\leq j<k\leq n}\bigg(a_k-a_j\bigg)=\begin{vmatrix}1&1&\cdots & 1 \\a_1 &a_2&\cdots &a_n \\ \vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\ a_1^{n-1}&a_2^{n-1}&\cdots&a_n^{n-1}\end{vmatrix}$$ If we expand this determinant using the first row, we have $$\prod\limits_{1\leq j<k\leq n}\bigg(a_k-a_j\bigg)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}\begin{vmatrix}a_1&\cdots&a_{i-1}&a_{i+1}&\cdots&a_n\\a_1^2&\cdots&a_{i-1}^2&a_{i+1}^2&\cdots&a_n^2\\\vdots&&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\a_1^{n-1}&\cdots&a_{i-1}^{n-1}&a_{i+1}^{n-1}&\cdots&a_n^{n-1}\end{vmatrix}$$
Also, the numerator can be written as $$\begin{aligned}(-1)^{i-1}\bigg(\prod\limits_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq i}}^na_j\bigg)\prod\limits_{\substack{1\leq j<k\leq n\\j,k\neq i}}\bigg(a_k-a_j\bigg)&=(-1)^{i-1}\bigg(\prod\limits_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq i}}^na_j\bigg)\begin{vmatrix}1&\cdots&1&1&\cdots&1\\a_1&\cdots&a_{i-1}&a_{i+1}&\cdots&a_n\\\vdots&&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\a_1^{n-2}&\cdots&a_{i-1}^{n-2}&a_{i+1}^{n-2}&\cdots&a_n^{n-2}\end{vmatrix}\\
&=(-1)^{i-1}\begin{vmatrix}a_1&\cdots&a_{i-1}&a_{i+1}&\cdots&a_n\\a_1^2&\cdots&a_{i-1}^2&a_{i+1}^2&\cdots&a_n^2\\\vdots&&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\a_1^{n-1}&\cdots&a_{i-1}^{n-1}&a_{i+1}^{n-1}&\cdots&a_n^{n-1}\end{vmatrix}\end{aligned}$$
Therefore $\displaystyle{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\ell_i(x)\equiv 1}$.
Using the same determinant strategy, $$\begin{aligned}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\prod\limits_{\substack{j=1\\ j\neq i}}^n\frac{1-x_ix_j}{x_i-x_j}&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}·\frac{\prod\limits_{\substack{j=1\\ j\neq i}}^n\bigg(1-x_ix_j\bigg)\prod\limits_{\substack{1\leq j<k\leq n\\j,k\neq i}}\bigg(x_k-x_j\bigg)}{\prod\limits_{1\leq j<k\leq n}\bigg(x_k-x_j\bigg)}\\
&=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}1&1&\cdots&1\\x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_n\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\x_1^{n-2}&x_2^{n-2}&\cdots&x_n^{n-2}\\\prod\limits_{j\neq 1}(1-x_1x_j)&\prod\limits_{j\neq 2}(1-x_2x_j)&\cdots&\prod\limits_{j\neq n}(1-x_nx_j)\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}1&1&\cdots&1\\x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_n\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\x_1^{n-1}&x_2^{n-1}&\cdots&x_n^{n-1}\end{vmatrix}}\end{aligned}$$ Therefore, the question then becomes how to prove $$\begin{vmatrix}1&1&\cdots&1\\x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_n\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\x_1^{n-2}&x_2^{n-2}&\cdots&x_n^{n-2}\\\prod\limits_{j\neq 1}(1-x_1x_j)&\prod\limits_{j\neq 2}(1-x_2x_j)&\cdots&\prod\limits_{j\neq n}(1-x_nx_j)\end{vmatrix}=\begin{cases}0,&\text{When}\;n\;\text{is even}\\\begin{vmatrix}1&1&\cdots&1\\x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_n\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\x_1^{n-1}&x_2^{n-1}&\cdots&x_n^{n-1}\end{vmatrix},&\text{When}\;n\;\text{is odd}\end{cases}$$
I've been struggling with this for a long time, and finally I come up with one ugly solution. First, I will introduce some notations. Let $$\binom{n}{k}=\sum\limits_{1\leq i_1<i_2<...<i_k\leq n}\prod\limits_{j=1}^kx_{i_j}$$ $$\binom{n-1}{k}_{i}=\sum\limits_{\substack{1\leq i_1<i_2<...<i_k\leq n\\i_1,i_2,...,i_k\neq i}}\prod\limits_{j=1}^kx_{i_j}$$
For instance $\displaystyle{\binom{4}{2}=x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4}$, $\displaystyle{\binom{4-1}{2}_2=\binom{3}{2}_2=x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_3x_4}$
Also, for the sake of simplicity I will use the following notations to represent
basic row operations. $$\text{Add}\;\lambda R_j\;\text{row}\;R_i:\;R_i\leftarrow R_i+\lambda R_j$$
Again, for simplicity, the last row of the determinant will be denoted by $$\bigg(\prod\limits_{j\neq i}(1-x_ix_j)\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}=\left(\begin{matrix}\prod\limits_{j\neq 1}(1-x_1x_j)&\prod\limits_{j\neq 2}(1-x_2x_j)&\cdots&\prod\limits_{j\neq n}(1-x_nx_j)\end{matrix}\right)$$
Since basic row operations will no change the value of the determinant, then if the last row of the determinant $$\bigg(\prod\limits_{j\neq i}(1-x_ix_j)\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}$$ becomes $$\bigg(\lambda x_i^k+\prod\limits_{j\neq i}(1-x_ix_j)\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}$$ for $\forall 0\leq k\leq n-2$ the determinant will not change since it's just $R_n\leftarrow R_n+\lambda R_{k+1}$
I will use $\approx$ to denote row operations that do not change the value of the determinant. For instance, $$\bigg(\prod\limits_{j\neq i}(1-x_ix_j)\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\approx\bigg(\lambda x_i^k+\prod\limits_{j\neq i}(1-x_ix_j)\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}$$
With the above notations, it is easy to verify that $\forall 1\leq i\leq n$, $$\begin{aligned}\bigg(\prod\limits_{j\neq i}(1-x_ix_j)\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}&=\bigg(1+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}(-x_i)^j\binom{n-1}{j}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}=\bigg(1\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\bigg((-x_i)^j\binom{n-1}{j}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&\approx\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\bigg((-x_i)^j\binom{n-1}{j}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\end{aligned}$$
The last step comes from $R_n\leftarrow R_n-R_1$. Note that it's actually the sum of $n-1$ rows, and I will handle these $n-1$ rows separately.
Now when $n$ is odd, I will show that $\displaystyle{\forall 1\leq j\leq\frac{n-1}{2}}$, we have $$\bigg((-x_i)^j\binom{n-1}{j}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\approx\bigg(x_i^{2j}\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}$$
To show this, we consider the first step $\displaystyle{\bigg((-x_i)^j\binom{n-1}{j}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\leftarrow \bigg((-x_i)^j\binom{n-1}{j}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}-\binom{n}{j}R_{j+1}}$
i.e., $$\begin{aligned}\bigg((-x_i)^j\binom{n-1}{j}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}&\approx \bigg((-x_i)^j\binom{n-1}{j}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}-\binom{n}{j}\bigg((-x_i)^j\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&=\bigg((-x_i)^j\binom{n-1}{j}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}-\bigg(\binom{n}{j}(-x_i)^j\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&=\bigg((-x_i)^j\binom{n-1}{j}_i-\binom{n}{j}(-x_i)^j\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&=\bigg((-x_i)^{j+1}\binom{n-1}{j-1}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\end{aligned}$$
Then consider the second step $\displaystyle{\bigg((-x_i)^{j+1}\binom{n-1}{j-1}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\leftarrow\bigg((-x_i)^{j+1}\binom{n-1}{j-1}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}-\binom{n}{j-1}R_{j+2}}$
i.e., $$\begin{aligned}\bigg((-x_i)^{j+1}\binom{n-1}{j-1}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}&\approx\bigg((-x_i)^{j+1}\binom{n-1}{j-1}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}-\binom{n}{j-1}\bigg((-x_i)^{j+1}\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&=\bigg((-x_i)^{j+2}\binom{n-1}{j-2}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\end{aligned}$$
By applying the similar procedure, one pattern becomes obvious $$\begin{aligned}\bigg((-x_i)^j\binom{n-1}{j}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}&\approx\bigg((-x_i)^{j+1}\binom{n-1}{j-1}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&\approx\bigg((-x_i)^{j+2}\binom{n-1}{j-2}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&\approx\bigg((-x_i)^{j+3}\binom{n-1}{j-3}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&\approx\cdots\\
&\approx\bigg((-x_i)^{2j}\binom{n-1}{0}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&=\bigg((-x_i)^{2j}\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&=\bigg(x_i^{2j}\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\end{aligned}$$
Note that when $\displaystyle{j\leq\frac{n-3}{2}}$, there is $\displaystyle{\bigg(x_i^{2j}\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\approx\bigg(0\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}}$
When $\displaystyle{j=\frac{n-1}{2}}$, there is $\displaystyle{\bigg(x_i^{2j}\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}=\bigg((x_i)^{n-1}\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}}$
Then I will show that when $\displaystyle{n-1\geq j\geq\frac{n+1}{2}}$, there is $\displaystyle{\bigg((-x_i)^j\binom{n-1}{j}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\approx\bigg(0\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}}$
Using the similar procedure, it is easy to verify that $$\begin{aligned}\bigg((-x_i)^j\binom{n-1}{j}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}&\approx\bigg((-x_i)^{j-1}\binom{n-1}{j+1}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&\approx\bigg((-x_i)^{j-2}\binom{n-1}{j+2}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&\approx\bigg((-x_i)^{j-3}\binom{n-1}{j+3}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&\approx\cdots\\
&\approx\bigg((-x_i)^{2j+1-n}\binom{n-1}{n-1}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&=\bigg((-x_i)^{2j-n}\binom{n}{n}\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&=\binom{n}{n}\bigg((-x_i)^{2j-n}\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&\approx\bigg(0\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\end{aligned}$$
Therefore, when $n$ is odd, $$\begin{aligned}\bigg(\prod\limits_{j\neq i}(1-x_ix_j)\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}
&\approx\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\bigg((-x_i)^j\binom{n-1}{j}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&=\sum\limits_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq\frac{n-1}{2}}}^{n-1}\bigg((-x_i)^j\binom{n-1}{j}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}+\bigg((-x_i)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\binom{n-1}{\frac{n-1}{2}}_i\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&\approx\sum\limits_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq\frac{n-1}{2}}}^{n-1}\bigg(0\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}+\bigg((x_i)^{n-1}\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\\
&=\bigg((x_i)^{n-1}\bigg)_{1\leq i\leq n}\end{aligned}$$
Thus, $\displaystyle{\begin{vmatrix}1&1&\cdots&1\\x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_n\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\x_1^{n-2}&x_2^{n-2}&\cdots&x_n^{n-2}\\\prod\limits_{j\neq 1}(1-x_1x_j)&\prod\limits_{j\neq 2}(1-x_2x_j)&\cdots&\prod\limits_{j\neq n}(1-x_nx_j)\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}1&1&\cdots&1\\x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_n\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\x_1^{n-1}&x_2^{n-1}&\cdots&x_n^{n-1}\end{vmatrix}}$ when $n$ is odd.
Similarly, it can be shown that $\displaystyle{\begin{vmatrix}1&1&\cdots&1\\x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_n\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\x_1^{n-2}&x_2^{n-2}&\cdots&x_n^{n-2}\\\prod\limits_{j\neq 1}(1-x_1x_j)&\prod\limits_{j\neq 2}(1-x_2x_j)&\cdots&\prod\limits_{j\neq n}(1-x_nx_j)\end{vmatrix}=0}$ when $n$ is even.
However, I think this proof is somehow too complicated and I'm wondering if there's a simpler solution. Plz help me if you have a better way of calculating the determinant. Thanks.
